# Unable to load background image with css property background-image: url() in codesandbox

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I'm trying to load my image which is inside src/images/hero.svg through css using background-image:url('./images/hero.svg') in codesandbox.[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFzTn.png).

Works fine when I try to access it inside function component with  but with css it's not loading[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BreQ.png)

Comment: have you tried to add the quote ("") ? (background-image: url("./images/hero.svg");

Comment: If you see where you have written css, you have not added quotes around the file path.
Example - url("./images/hero.svg")

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add images in the css:
so for adding images in css with the use of the url specified as follows :
code for adding background image in CSS:

background-image: linear-gradient(rgba (4,2,54,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(url of the image);

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way around this is to note use a local address.  Find an image somewhere on the web.