# Background images not working on Codesandbox React

Tags: css, reactjs, codesandbox

I can't get background images to load in CodeSandbox.  What's going on?  [Another user asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74691268/unable-to-load-background-image-with-css-property-background-image-url-in-cod) but didn't get an adequate answer.  I tried putting quotation marks.  So what's the deal?

Here is my [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/book-sl1j36?file=/src/style.css).  Neither the wooden 'desk" background nor the...erm, papery "paper" background shows up.  When I run this locally it works fine.